# Go test "-run -" flag executed tests much faster

Tags: go, testing, go-testing, roaring-bitset

I was looking at some benchmark tests from https://github.com/RoaringBitmap/roaring

When running a specific benchmark using `-run -` (as mentioned in there [comments](https://github.com/RoaringBitmap/roaring/blob/21f5fe717bc5377a0ab7a59a504d1f35caf0c369/benchmark_test.go)):
`go test -bench BenchmarkNexts -benchmem -run -` It seems to execute faster, at least running it without `-run -` seems to have some initial overhead of 5 seconds also this is plotted:

```
==roaring==
{1,2,3,4,5,100,1000}
{3,4,1000}
{}
Cardinality:  7
Contains 3?  true
1
3
4
5
1000

Wrote  22  bytes
I wrote the content to a byte stream and read it back.
size before run optimize: 1810 bytes, and after: 38 bytes.
```

As the `-run` flag runs tests based on a regex pattern it seems like something is excluded here but what exactly as both run the same tests the only difference is the initial overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Go test "-run -" flag executed tests much faster

That is the expected result. It's faster when you don't run any tests.

To see what is being executed, add the `-v` option to your `go test` executions.

Run no tests:

```
go clean -testcache && go test -bench BenchmarkNexts -benchmem -run - -v
```

Run all tests:

```
go clean -testcache && go test -bench BenchmarkNexts -benchmem -v`
```

or, since `-run .` is equivalent to all tests,

```
go clean -testcache && go test -bench BenchmarkNexts -benchmem -run . -v
```

---

> [Go is a tool for managing Go source code.](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go)
>
> Testing flags
>
> ```
> -run regexp
>     Run only those tests, examples, and fuzz tests matching the regular
>     expression.
>
> -v
>     Verbose output: log all tests as they are run.
> ```
>
> Build and test caching
>
> The go command also caches successful package test results. See 'go help test' for details. Running 'go clean -testcache' removes all cached test results (but not cached build results).

Comment: So if I understand correctly ```go test -bench BenchmarkNexts -benchmem``` will run only specific benchmarks based on the regex but will always still execute all the tests ?

Comment: @Chris: Yes. In regexp terms  it's equivalent to `-run .`: `$ go clean -testcache && go test -bench BenchmarkNexts -benchmem -run . -v`.